# How many copies of assembly does .net framework 4 installer install to my machine?

Tags: .net, installation, gac

Take `System.dll` for an example:

I found one here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.dll`

one here: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.dll`

and one here: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll`

Why can't we just have only the one in GAC?

Comment: What makes you think those are copies? Did you compare them?

Comment: @John Saunders they all have this signature: System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Comment: the second one and third one are the same size. i dont know if they have the same content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DLL files in the `Reference Assemblies` folder are stub files that contain member declarations and no actual code.

They're used by Visual Studio to show you which members are available in the profile you're targetting.
You'll see different sets of reference assemblies, with non-identical DLL files, for the Client Profile, Portable Class Libraries, and Metro-style apps.

Comment: thanks, then what about the one under "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"? this one is full-sized.

Comment: That's the standard copy; the GAC is not meant to store files.  (AFAIK; I may be wrong about this)